# Showing different pop-ups on click of a table element

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am very new to VueJS. I am trying to populate a table. One of the columns is a button on clicking which a modal opens. There can be 3 different types of modals. I   tried solving the problem like this :

I have linked my jsfiddle after this reference code.

HTML

```
 <div id="app">

  <!-- Main table element -->
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" >
    <template slot="name" slot-scope="item">
      {{item.value.first}} {{item.value.last}}
    </template>
    <template slot="isActive" slot-scope="item">
      {{item.value?'Yes :)':'No :('}}
    </template>
    <template slot="actions" slot-scope="item">
      <div v-if="item.item.age < 15">
        <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1 size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="item.item.age > 26">
        <b-btn v-b-modal.modal2 size="sm"           @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>        
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <b-btn v-b-modal.modal3 size="sm"           @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
      </div>

    </template>
  </b-table>

  <b-modal id="modal1">
    modal 1
  </b-modal>

    <b-modal id="modal2">
    modal 2
  </b-modal>
  <b-modal id="modal3">
    modal3
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

VueJS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }
    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 9,
      state: 'success',
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 89,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 40,
      name: {
        first: 'Dickerson',
        last: 'Macdonald'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 21,
      name: {
        first: 'Larsen',
        last: 'Shaw'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 26,
      name: {
        first: 'Mitzi',
        last: 'Navarro'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 22,
      name: {
        first: 'Geneva',
        last: 'Wilson'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: true,
      age: 38,
      name: {
        first: 'Jami',
        last: 'Carney'
      }

    }, {
      isActive: false,
      age: 27,
      name: {
        first: 'Essie',
        last: 'Dunlap'
      }

    }],
    fields: {
      name: {
        label: 'Person Full name',
        sortable: true
      },
      age: {
        label: 'Person age',
        sortable: true
      },
      isActive: {
        label: 'is Active'
      },
      actions: {
        label: 'Actions'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    details(item) {
      //gets some data. Write 3 different functions to fetch data accordingly 
    }
  }
})
```

Style:

```
#app {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**Update:**

I was able to replicate the bug described below here after I added pagination.

my fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2qcy3ne/)

To replicate, go to a different page and try opening all of the modals. Some will not open.

**Observation:**

I see that I am able to open only one modal per page after I change to a different page from the initial page.

Is there any better way of doing this? Or am I missing something trivial?

**Bug descriptoin:**

I am running into a strange behavior in my code where most of the rows(seems random to me) don't open a pop-up when the button is clicked.This happens even for the same modal type

Eg : Suppose P,Q entries of the column  are of type modal1. Clicking on P opens a modal and clicking on Q does not.

I know this bug seems vague but I will be very glad if some one could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't explain why this happens (maybe is a bug of bootstrap-vue). Anyway, if you replace:

```
<b-btn v-b-modal.modal1 size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
<b-btn v-b-modal.modal2 size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
<b-btn v-b-modal.modal3 size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
```

with:

```
<b-btn v-b-modal="'modal1'" size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
<b-btn v-b-modal="'modal2'" size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
<b-btn v-b-modal="'modal3'" size="sm" @click="details(item.item)">Details</b-btn>
```

it seems to work fine.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes it seems that this does fix the issue, I had already raised an [issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2045) on their github. I have further updated it with your comments. Thanks for taking out your time and trying this out.

Comment: Hi Fabio. I just looked more into the issue. The modals are opening now for all the entries. But some of them open the wrong modals. Can you please check and verify once. I have updated the age parameters, made your suggested changes and have made a new fiddle : [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1y6dtp4s/)

Comment: @nighthowler It looks like the modals are always opening based on the order of the first page. I don't know bootstrap-vue a lot, maybe you should set a key for your items in some way, but I can't find anything about it.